# Public synonym_OracleSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a public synonym in my code, however, I am unable to see it in the all_synonyms or user_synonyms views just to make sure the synonym has created and existed in my database. Help me guys?! Thanks in advance...

I have tried to look in the user_synonyms and all_synonyms or dba_synonyms vies, still unable to find it.

```
create public synonym EBS_PS as select * from EBS;
(Synonym created)
```

I should see the public synonym EBS_PS should be stored in a system view.

Comment: You apparently didn't catch errors in your code when you created the synonym. Because that SQL is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not a valid Oracle statement:

```
SQL> create public synonym EBS_PS as select * from EBS;
create public synonym EBS_PS as select * from EBS
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

To create the synonym you want you do:

```
create public synonym EBS_PS for EBS;
```

This will show up in the all_synonyms view.

Answer (score 0):

On the future, I can advice that you should use "or replace" keyword. You can save time for solving the next errors.

```
create or replace public synonym EBS_PS for EBS;
```